# Invalid object name 'Table'  when performing CRUD operation when using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crud, common-table-expression

Hi I am currently creating My SP that insert and detete records based on the result given by my select statement.

This is my sample  Code:

```
DECLARE @PickListBatchName varchar(200),
@PartNumber varchar(50),
@QTY int;

SET @PickListBatchName='TEST1';
SET @PartNumber='PN1';
SET @QTY=1;


      --STEP 1 Add Result to TempTable
      With SN as
      (
        SELECT TOP (@QTY) 
           pb.PickListBatchId
           ,pt.PickListTRANId
           ,pt.SerialNumber
           ,pt.Createdby
           ,pt.CreatedDT
FROM PickListTRAN pt 
            LEFT JOIN PickListBatchDetail pdb ON pdb.PickListBatchDetailId=pt.PickListBatchDetailId
            LEFT JOIN PickListBatch pb ON pdb.PickListBatchId=pb.PickListBatchId
where  pb.PickListBatchName=@PickListBatchName AND pdb.PartNumber=@PartNumber
      )


    --STEP 2: INSERT SN TO PicklistTranCancel
    INSERT INTO PickListTRANCancel
   (
   PickListBatchId
   ,SerialNumber
   ,CreatedBy
   ,CreatedDT
   ) 
   (SELECT  
           PickListBatchId,
           SerialNumber,
           Createdby,
           CreatedDT
    FROM SN);

    --STEP 3: DELETE Records on PicklistTran

    DELETE FROM PicklistTran where picklistTranId IN (SELECT PickListTRANId FROM SN)
```

result:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
Invalid object name 'SN'.  --error on delete statement
```

On Step 3, the delete statement cannot read SN table. maybe i'm missing something on that part.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @benni_mac_b and @praveen this is what i tried. I just use to create TempTable instead of using WITH.

```
DECLARE @PickListBatchName varchar(200),
@PartNumber varchar(50),
@QTY int;

SET @PickListBatchName='TEST1';
SET @PartNumber='PN1';
SET @QTY=1;

Declare @MyTable table 
(
     PickListBatchId int,
     PickListTRANId int,
    SerialNumber varchar(50),
    Createdby varchar(50),
    CreatedDT datetime
);


 --STEP 1: insert to temptable 
 INSERT INTO @MyTable
                    (
           PickListBatchId,
           PickListTRANId,
           SerialNumber,
           Createdby,
           CreatedDT
                    )
SELECT TOP (@QTY) 
           pb.PickListBatchId
           ,pt.PickListTRANId
           ,pt.SerialNumber
           ,pt.Createdby
           ,pt.CreatedDT
FROM PickListTRAN pt 
            LEFT JOIN PickListBatchDetail pdb ON pdb.PickListBatchDetailId=pt.PickListBatchDetailId
            LEFT JOIN PickListBatch pb ON pdb.PickListBatchId=pb.PickListBatchId
where  pb.PickListBatchName=@PickListBatchName AND pdb.PartNumber=@PartNumber


    --STEP 2: INSERT SN TO PicklistTranCancel
    INSERT INTO PickListTRANCancel
   (
   PickListBatchId
   ,SerialNumber
   ,CreatedBy
   ,CreatedDT
   ) 
   SELECT  
   PickListBatchId,
   SerialNumber,
   Createdby,
   CreatedDT
   FROM @MyTable

   --STEP 3: DELETE
   DELETE FROM PicklistTran where picklistTranId IN (SELECT PickListTRANId FROM @MyTable)
```

Answer (score 6):

In your code CTE is only accessible till insert statement . If you need to access the CTE table ,try to populate the CTE data into a @TempTable and then access it in your delete statements .You can modify your code to store the value into a temporary table

```
 INSERT INTO PickListTRANCancel

  (
  PickListBatchId
  ,SerialNumber
  ,CreatedBy
  ,CreatedDT
  ) 
Output   Inserted.PickListBatchId,Inserted.SerialNumber,Inserted.CreatedBy,
Inserted.CreatedDT into @TempTable
  (SELECT  
       PickListBatchId,
       SerialNumber,
       Createdby,
       CreatedDT
FROM SN);

   DELETE FROM PicklistTran where picklistTranId IN
   (SELECT PickListTRANId FROM @TempTable)
```

I haven't verified the code but this way you can frame your query .

Answer (score 2):

A CTE is a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, or CREATE VIEW statement. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

The CTE is no longer available in the second statement as as mentioned above they are only available for one statement.

Answer (score 0):

CTE scope get available only for one statement,you can not use it twice. you can use temporary table to store the value of CTE